# Concatenar vários ficheiros sass/css em um só css final

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, sass, webpack

Estou a usar laravel 5.4, que por default traz um ficheiro `webpack.mix.js` que serão os ficheiros a serem concatenados e o seu destino.

O meu problema é concatenar ficheiros `scss` com `css`, o que tenho em `webpack.mix.js` é:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.autoload({});
mix.scripts([
        'assets/js/jquery.min.js',
        'assets/js/custom.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass([
        'assets/css/app.css',
        'assets/css/app.scss'
    ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Quando corro `npm run production` ou `npm run dev` o seguinte erro ocorre:

> AssertionError: mix.sass() is missing required parameter 1: src

Já se tiver o `webpack.mix.js` com `.css([...` em vez de `.sass([...` ele ignora o conteúdo do ficheiro `assets/css/app.scss` e põe no ficheiro destino apenas o conteúdo do `assets/css/app.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de concatenar usando o `webpack.mix.js`, você poderia fazer assim, no seu arquivo `assets/css/app.scss`:

```
@import "app.css" // supondo que o arquivo app.css está no mesmo nível que app.scss
@import "foo/bar" // vai incluir um arquivo bar.scss que está dentro do diretório foo...

// restante do scss...
```

Dessa forma seu `webpack.mix.js` continuará como default:

```
// código existente omitido...

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Obrigado é uma solução, mas e se eu tiver dois ficheiros scss? Para colocar no mesmo css destino

Comment: O mesmo se aplica.

Comment: "Failed at the @ production script", quando corro npm production